# Emberjs select binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

### Here is the JsBin: http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/118

### go **info->contact !!**

I have some customers:

```
var customers = {
  "customers":[
    {"id":3,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","contact":{"id":2,"name":"NY"}},
    {"id":2,"name":"Rox","bio":"mo' tex","contact":{"id":1,"name":"LA"}}
  ]
};
```

and a set of locations:

```
var locations = {
  "location":[
    {"id":1,"name":"LA"},
    {"id":2,"name":"NY"},
    {"id":3,"name":"TKY"},
    {"id":4,"name":"JIB"},
    {"id":5,"name":"VIE"}

  ]
};
```

I populate the my select from the locations, and i try to set it's value and option according to my customer's contact, but it doesnt work. There is an another select where i can set it but only if the valuePath and labelPath set to "name" and the select's  value too.

```
{{view Ember.Select
   content=model.location
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.name"
   selection="modal.customer.contact.id"
   value="model.customer.contact.id"
   prompt="Please select a location"
   }}
```

I have looked http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html, but maybe im missing something.

I also dont understand what is the different between the selection and value properties.
In the documentation why is "Tom" selected if `selection=selectedPerson` where `selectedPerson=null`

**My bonus question:)** Is it possible to bind the select's value to an object? eg to customer's contact.

```
{"id":3,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","contact":{"id":2,"name":"NY"}}
```

i change the select's value to: 5

```
{"id":3,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","contact":{"id":5,"name":"VIE"}}
```

or do i have to do it by hand; search the object with id 5 in locations, and replace customer's content with it.

### !! Edit !!

I have managed

- to use selectionBinding: if i change the select the customers' contact will be chaged to the proper location object.
- i can set **manually** the select. see `preselect` property. But i dont get it why must it be string, when `id` is number, and i still cant set to the selected customer's contact id.

Anyway here is the updated JsBin : http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/126

Comment: see my edit and updated JsBin

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your JSbin here:
http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/134

Your biggest problem was that you referenced the location objects wrongly.
You should have referenced the locations defined in the locations fixture by id, like this :

```
App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    bio:DS.attr(),
    contact:DS.belongsTo('location')
});

var customers = {
  "customers":[
    {"id":3,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","contact":2},
    {"id":2,"name":"Rox","bio":"mo' tex","contact":1}
  ]
};
```

Such that Ember could relate the objects in the select's content, to the same objects in the customers contact field.

Comment: thank you! but im getting the data from server in this structure, and i cant flatten it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Ember Data internals, but I believe this calls for a custom serialiser to fix this non-standard server reply  on the client side, or a use of DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin to handle the embedded contacts.

Comment: hmm. you were right. my payload is far away what ember data expects. who sets this standards? https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration